# Relationship between table is not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `user` and `profile`. Profile table had `user_id` as foreign key. I have related the two tables.

In tinker I can see that relation is made but in code its not fetching the details from other table.

I have also tried

```
return $this->belongsTo('User::class');
```

**User Model**

```
public function profile() {
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}
```

**Profile Model**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Comment: The correct answer has been given below, plus something to add, `$this->belongsTo(User::class);` you should lose that quotes('')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things that are not completely right.

In tinker to obtain the profile of user insert this lines:

```
$user = User::find([user_id]);
```

And then :

```
$user->profile();
```

If you want to associate the ::class you should use:

```
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
```

If you want to use the string association should use:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
```

Another tip is every time you change a controller you have to close and open tinker again

Comment: If I do return '$this->belongsTo('App\User');' then it works

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify keys for `hasOne` and `belongsTo` method as below:

```
 $this->hasOne('Profile', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

 $this->belongsTo('User', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Look also on one to one relation:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: This is the correct answer because the relationship definitions will only work automagically if the table names are pluralized (i.e. `users` and `profiles`).